# Unable to get Swagger UI working with Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to get Swagger UI working with Spring Boot 1.2.1. I followed the instructions at https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc and I added `@EnableSwagger` on my spring config.

I currently get back JSON when I go to `http://localhost:8080/api-docs` but no nice HTML.

I am using Maven and added the dependency on swagger-ui:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ajar</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-spring-mvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my complete list of dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ajar</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-spring-mvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I also tried `http://localhost:8080/docs/index.html` as URL, but that just gives the "Whitelabel Error Page"

Update:

I created a test project on Github to show the problem: https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/springboot-swagger-test

Comment: Have you tried http://localhost:8080/sdoc.jsp or http://localhost:8080/app/sdoc.jsp?

Comment: @Ron Just tried it now, but does not work.

Comment: Just followed what's written here - https://github.com/adrianbk/swagger-springmvc-demo/tree/master/swagger-ui - if you don't get a reply here, I'd suggest opening an issue on that repository. Adrian is very responsive.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your problem lies in your `SwaggerConfiguration` file. You need to take out `@EnableWebMvc`, because this causes the default Spring Boot view resolver to be overwritten by the default 'SpringWebMvc' one which serves static content differently.

By default, Spring Boot will serve static content from any of the following directories:

- /META-INF/resources/
- /resources/
- /static/
- /public/

including webjars.

I had the same problem and I found this in the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration

> If you want to take complete control of Spring MVC, you can add your own `@Configuration` annotated with `@EnableWebMvc`. If you want to keep Spring Boot MVC features, and you just want to add additional MVC configuration (interceptors, formatters, view controllers etc.) you can add your own `@Bean` of type `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, but **without** `@EnableWebMvc`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It's helping people in 2019 as well :)

Comment: I don't have ´@EnableWebMvc` but still facing empty page problem.

Comment: where is `SwaggerConfiguration` file located?

Answer (score 4):

I have swagger-ui v0.4 (with spring v4.14 & swagger-springmvc v0.9.4) working fine, although I had some similar problems at first. It seems like this class does the trick.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig;

    @Bean
    public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin customImplementation() {
        return new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(springSwaggerConfig).apiInfo(
                apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfo(/* strings */);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

I believe the relevant thing is the overridden `configureDefaultServletHandling`. And on my main `WebApplicationInitializer`, I have:

```
@Import(SwaggerConfig.class)
```

Finally, I fixed the issue with the UI's location box showing "http://localhost:8080${pageContext.request.contextPath}/api-docs" by including this in my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <!--<version>8.0.15</version>-->
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

That provides something related to JSP processing. It is included in the dependencies of `spring-boot`, but it isn't normally `provided`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: whats the jar file for the ApiInfo in the above code?

Comment: @Chandra `springfox-core`

Answer (score 3):

If you are experiencing this issue with version springfox swagger-ui 3.x or greater..

try the below url.. It worked for me..

[http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui](http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/)/

For complete swagger documentations steps, refer:
http://muralitechblog.com/swagger-rest-api-dcoumentation-for-spring-boot/

Comment: this worked for me as I'm using pringfox swagger-ui 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue but this link works for me: http://localhost:8080/sdoc.jsp

It pre-populates the swagger ui resource url box with : 
http://localhost:8080${pageContext.request.contextPath}/api-docs

and when I hand edit it removing ${pageContext.request.contextPath} and hit Explore it shows me my api doc and I can even try my endpoints successfully. So definitely an issue but probably not picking up ${pageContext.request/contextPath}.

Looking at the source the javascript has:
url: window.location.origin + "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/api-docs"

on a static swagger ui html I have this piece is coded as:

discoveryUrl:"./resource-list.json"

I hope this is a bit helpful

Comment: Spring Boot does not render JSPs properly.  See https://github.com/adrianbk/swagger-springmvc-demo/issues/15

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by Tamas above, the problem lies in using @EnableWebMvc, which goes around the default setup and skips some things Swagger needs. Switching that to @EnableSwagger2 for me was enough to fix the issues in my project, which showed similar symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issues in my project. resolved issue with below steps.

**Added below dependencies in pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Added swagger2 ui configuration as below in the project level**

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SpringFoxConfig {  
    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build();                                           
    }
    
}
```

Then able to get the **swagger ui documentation** http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/

**swagger api docs** http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs

Answer (score -2):

I have done separate config for Swagger and my problem was that without `@EnableAutoConfiguration` it was not working properly.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest you to use @EnableSwagger2 tag and follow the steps and code from here: https://github.com/sanketsw/SpringBoot_REST_API

Also i am using following dependency which works perfectly fine:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Linking to external resources is fine, but links can change dramatically or break entirely over time. Please include enough information to implement a solution in your answer without the need to rely on external information.

Comment: The detailed answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34307496/advice-about-swagger-api/35907962#35907962