# Swagger UI displays ${pageContext.request.contextPath} in location url

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I just added Swagger to my web application but when I display the UI the location url shows this:

```
http://localhost:8080${pageContext.request.contextPath}/api-docs
```

I had a look to [Unable to get Swagger UI working with Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27861872/unable-to-get-swagger-ui-working-with-spring-boot) and [Not getting things working with Spring Boot](https://github.com/adrianbk/swagger-springmvc-demo/issues/15) and added the `tomcat-embed-jasper` dependency as suggested

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

but I can still see the `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` in the url. I am using version `1.0.2` of `swagger-springmvc` and version `0.4` of `swagger-spring-mvc-ui`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ajar</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-spring-mvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>0.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any help or suggestion on how to solve this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at [this issue](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/496)? Also I think you should upgrade to 2.x of springfox.

Comment: I did, but it did not work. I will try springfox but I have the feeling that I am missing something obvious. Thanks @DilipKrishnan

Comment: If moving to 2.x isn't an option you could manually copy swagger-ui to your resources folder and configure it [similar to this](https://github.com/springfox/springfox-demos/blob/master/spring-java-swagger/src/main/java/springfoxdemo/java/swagger/SpringConfig.java). There is nothing magical about the web jar solution that comes out of the box.

Comment: @DilipKrishnan Thanks for the suggestion. I moved to 2.x of springfox and it worked out of the box.